# Node.js - Communicating with just proxy server while making request over HTTPS

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-request, https-proxy-agent

I am sending https requests using a proxy server. I want to pass certain information back and forth with only the proxy server (not passed to the destination server). This can be done easily with request headers when doing HTTP requests, but for HTTPS requests the headers are encrypted so using request headers is not an option. My proxy server provides the following option when using HTTPS:

> The only point at which unencrypted data is sent to the proxy server
>   is with the initial CONNECT method. This is where you must insert the
>   custom headers. Similarly, the proxy server cannot inject an extra
>   header into the final response. Instead, the response header is
>   injected immediately after the Connection response, which looks like
>   this:
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
>  
>   X-ProxyServer-IP: 123.456.789.000
>   *final response headers & body*

So the I need to pass headers with the CONNECT method, and read the CONNECT response. It seems that the `https-proxy-agent` module will allow specifying headers to be sent specifically with the CONNECT request. But how can I read the CONNECT response, while still completing the intended request (e.g. POST)?

I cannot figure out how to intercept the CONNECT response with either the `request` module or `https` module.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested `https`

```
const https = require('https');
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
var server = https.createServer(function(req,res){res.end('test');}).listen(3000);
```

If you `console.log(server._events)`

```
{ connection: [ [Function], [Function] ],
  secureConnection: [ [Function: connectionListener], [Function] ],
  request: [Function],
  tlsClientError: [ [Function: addListener], [Function] ] }
```

So after adding the following :

```
server.on('connection',function(req,socket,head){console.log('CONNECT')})
server.on('secureConnection',function(req,socket,head){console.log('CONNECT (secure)')})
server.on('tlsClientError',function(req,socket,head){console.log('TLS:ERROR')})
```

I tested with : `curl -X CONNECT localhost:3000`

In this fast test the client output : 
`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`)

...but @ the server :

```
CONNECT
TLS:ERROR
```

As you can see its intercepting the `CONNECT` (even thou it has tls error due to testing env.),

So if you do this with your (working) setup you will be able of intercept it without the `TLS:ERROR`

---

For anyone that wants to do it with `http` , the event is different : `server.on('connect', ...`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think you misunderstood my question. I do not control the proxy server. I am the client and am trying to send a request via HTTPS (using node), but intercept the CONNECT response, before getting the request response.